# Onclick event to remove default value in a text input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input field:

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name">
```

How would I get it to remove the pre-defined text (Enter Your Name) when the user clicks the box.

As far as I am aware Javascript is the best way to do this. If that wrong please inform me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### HTML5 Placeholder Attribute

You are likely wanting `placeholder` functionality:

```
<input name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
```

#### Polyfill for Older Browsers

This will not work in some older browsers, but [polyfills exist](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (some require jQuery, others don't) to patch that functionality.

#### "Screw it, I'll do it myself."

If you wanted to roll your own solution, you could use the `onfocus` and `onblur` events of your element to determine what its value should be:

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name"
       onfocus="(this.value == 'Enter Your Name') && (this.value = '')"
       onblur="(this.value == '') && (this.value = 'Enter Your Name')" />
```

#### Avoid Mixing HTML with JavaScript

You'll find that most of us aren't big fans of evaluating JavaScript from attributes like `onblur` and `onfocus`. Instead, it's more commonly encouraged to bind this logic up purely with JavaScript. Granted, it's a bit more verbose, but it keeps a nice separation between your logic and your markup:

```
var nameElement = document.forms.myForm.Name;

function nameFocus( e ) {
  var element = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
  if (element.value == "Enter Your Name") element.value = "";
}

function nameBlur( e ) {
  var element = e.target || window.event.srcElement;
  if (element.value == "") element.value = "Enter Your Name";
}

if ( nameElement.addEventListener ) {
  nameElement.addEventListener("focus", nameFocus, false);
  nameElement.addEventListener("blur", nameBlur, false);
} else if ( nameElement.attachEvent ) {
  nameElement.attachEvent("onfocus", nameFocus);
  nameElement.attachEvent("onblur", nameBlur);
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/azehum/2/edit

Comment: for the next 2 or 3 years, probably, we should still consider some IE fallbacks.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but there is no point in loading an entire library for such a small matter

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 Polyfills aren't libraries. Polyfills often times fix only the thing you want fixed.

Comment: A list of polyfills for the input[placeholder] can be found here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills and you can do IE conditional comments to only load this file for old IE browsers.

Comment: @Evgeny It's a great list - I provided a link in my answer as well.

Comment: The only problem I will bring up is that of inline JavaScript being a bad pattern to encourage. I take back my upvote.

Comment: @kalisjoshua I agree. I was merely following the format used by the OP. I'll update the question.

Comment: You should use input.defaultValue instead of typing it every time again and again...

Answer (score 4):

This is the right, cross-browser way to do it :

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="if(this.value  == 'Enter Your Name') { this.value = ''; } " onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Your Name'; } " />
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `onclick="this.value=''"`:

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name" onclick="this.value=''">
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated before I even saw this question `placeholder` is the answer. HTML5 for the win! But for those poor unfortunate souls that cannot rely on that functionality take a look at the jquery plugin as an augmentation as well. [HTML5 Placeholder jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder)

```
<input name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
```

Answer (score 2):

u can use placeholder and when u write a text on the search box placeholder will hidden.
Thanks

```
<input placeholder="Search" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

***HTML***

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name" onClick="blankDefault('Enter Your Name', this)">
```

***JavaScript***

```
function blankDefault(_text, _this) {
    if(_text == _this.value)
        _this.value = '';
}
```

There are better/less obtrusive ways though, but this will get the job done.

Comment: Please, no one use this method. It will work until the developer forgets to ignore the value "Enter Your Name" or an actual person wants to submit that as a valid value; [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)... anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You actually want to show a placeholder, HTML 5 offer this feature and it's very sweet !

Try this out :

```
<input name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="freez(this)" onblur="freez(this)">


function freez(obj)
{
 if(obj.value=='')
 {
   obj.value='Enter Your Name';
 }else if(obj.value=='Enter Your Name')
 {
   obj.value='';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `placeholder="your text"` you could also do `onclick="this.value='';`

So it would look something like:

```
<input name="Name" value="Enter Your Name" onclick="this.value='';>
```