# HTML - Make form values disappear, and control the height, and width of text inputs

Tags: html, forms

I am creating a websites, and I have came across a predicament with my coding.

I am writing a 'submit form' and I need it to look like the following example:

Message: (Gives the user to submit a message, or type any comments) And inside the text box, I'd like for it to say 'Type your message here' but when you click within the box, the 'type your message here' disappears. I also would like to be able to control how large this text box is. 
Name: Type your first and last name here (I want it to function the same as above) 
Email Address: Type your email address here: (Again, function same as above)

This, is the code that I have so far, and I am not sure if it's correct or not, for what I'm trying to do:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:youremail@youremail.com" >

<b>Message:</b><br><input type="textbox" value="text_name" onfocus="if (this.value=='Text_name') this.value='';" style="width: 300px;" style="height: 300px;"/><br/>

<b>Name:</b><br><input type="text" name="First and Last" size="30" maxlength="30" /><br />

<b>Email:</b><br><input type="text" name="Email" size="24" maxlength="24" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Send Email" /> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of plugins available fir this. But you can use a HTML5 property "placeholder"

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name...">
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ky4Jp/1/)** is the demo. Text/hint will diappear as you start typing.

```
<b>Message:</b><br><input type="textbox" placeholder="Type your message here"   style="width: 300px;" style="height: 300px;"/><br/>

<b>Name:</b><br><input type="text" name="First and Last" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="Type your first and last name here" /><br />

<b>Email:</b><br><input type="text" name="Email" size="24" maxlength="24" placeholder="Type your email address here"/><br />

<input type="submit" value="Send Email" />
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this is pretty much a duplicate of: [Onclick event to remove default value in a text input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10637900/onclick-event-to-remove-default-value-in-a-text-input-field) right?

If you are fine with HTML5 then you can use [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) otherwise you will need to use Javascript that removes the text [onblur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364015/textarea-onclick-remove-text)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use bootstrap css for better styling. Just have a look at this http://getbootstrap.com/css/ . I hope this would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

You can define a script and use the below function since it can be used for both `onfocus` and `onblur`,

```
function clearText(field) {
    if(field.defaultValue == field.value) {
        field.value = “”;
    }
    else
        if(field.value == “”) {
            field.value = field.defaultValue;
        }
}
```